# wordpress shortcode content is showing two times

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a shortcode for wordpress.

using the shortcode in word file as :

```
add_shortcode('LATEST_NOT_ROHIT','latest_notification_rohit');
function latest_notification_rohit()
{
    include("shortcode.php");
}
```

in `shortcode.php` file the code is as follow :

```
<div class='alert alert-info'>Latest Notifications</div>

<?php
global $wpdb;
$select_qury = "select * from `ln_category`";
$select_cat = $wpdb->get_results($select_qury);
foreach($select_cat as $select_cat)
{
    echo "<h4>Latest Notifications For <span style='color:#800000'>".$select_cat->category."</span></h4>";
    $cat_id = $select_cat->id;

    $select_qury2 = "select * from `ln_notification` where `cat_id`='$cat_id'";
    $select_notification = $wpdb->get_results($select_qury2);
?>
<table class="responsive display table table-bordered">
<tr><th>Sr No</th><th>Organisation</th><th>Post Name</th><th>No of Post</th><th>Qualification</th><th>Fees</th><th>Adervst Date</th><th>Application Start Date</th>
<th>Application Last Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($select_notification as $select_notification)
{
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $start_date = $select_notification->start_date;
    $last_date = $select_notification->last_date;
    if($current_date < $start_date)
    {
        $remark = "<span style='color:green'>Form is about to start</span>";
    }
    elseif($current_date > $last_date)
    {
        $remark ="<span style='color:red'>Last Date is over</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        $remark = "Application is going on";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>".$select_notification->organisation."</td><td>".$select_notification->post_name."</td><td>".$select_notification->no_of_post.
    "</td><td>".$select_notification->qualification."</td><td>".$select_notification->fees."</td><td>".date('d-M-Y',strtotime($select_notification->adv_date))."</td><td>".date('d-M-Y',strtotime($start_date))."</td><td>".date('d-M-Y',strtotime($last_date))."</td><td>$remark</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

but when I am running this code in wordpress page/post then the content is displayed two times. The demo is at the front end

http://singhalrohitashv.com/latest-notification/

How can I resolve this problem ???

Comment: Try to include file with `include_once()` function.

Comment: not working ...

Comment: it shows the data once but it shows in header only

Comment: How you call shortcode in content area ?

Comment: Just seen your url, where did you called the shortcode and how, can you please give it here.

Comment: Have you tried with `require_once()` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_shortcode('LATEST_NOT_ROHIT','latest_notification_rohit');
function latest_notification_rohit()
{
    ob_start();
    require_once("shortcode.php");
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}
```

Would you please try above code?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling the **latest_notification_rohit()** function on one of the following files :

- Header.php for the page
- Page template file

You might also be calling the content function twice for that page. Doing a search all for **the_content()** or **latest_notification_rohit()** might show you the places where the code is being called multiple times.

Comment: I have put all of the code in question where I cant see the code running for the two times

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your code, you have used two **foreach** loop.

```
$select_qury = "select * from `ln_category`"; 
$select_cat = $wpdb->get_results($select_qury);
```

Possibly it returning two category which let first **foreach** executing two time. And as your table just before the second **foreach** loop, even it has no record it will print second table. Please put condition to print the table if record is there.

Hope this help you to solve the issue.